# Is there a Godot equivalent of VelocityChange (like in Unity3D)?

Tags: unity, movement, godot

In my Pong game the pressing of the required key and the actual movement has a delay in b/w. I believe this is because the force is building momentum and then moving, a problem I solve in Unity by using `ForceMode.VelocityChange`.

Also, could it be that I am taking input in `_physics_process()`?

Is there any way of solving this problem in Godot?

Comment: "the force is building momentum and then moving" does not sound right. I'm unfamiliar with `ForceMode.VelocityChange`. You are using Rigid Bodies, right? Is this 2D or 3D? Godot forgets 3D forces from one frame to the next (so the "building momentum" idea just makes no sense). By the way, there is no problem with taking input in `_physics_process()`. Chances are there is a simpler way to do what you are trying to do in Godot, but for finer control over a rigid body, you can implement `_integrate_forces`.

Comment: By the way, the recommended way to implement player characters in Godot is using Kinematic Bodies. Which do not work with impulses and forces. Which also means you are not limited by having to use impulses and forces to move them. However, there are legitimate use cases for player characters implemented as Rigid Bodies. What I'm saying is that in trying to make a Pong game the way you would in Unity but in Godot, you might be making things harder for yourself.